# Backbone JS: Validating required nested attributes/models?

Tags: validation, backbone.js

If I have a Backbone model who's `defaults` object looks like this:

```
defaults {
  "id" : null
  "name" : null,
  "url" : null,
  "admin" : {
    "id" : null,
    "email" : null
  }
}
```

is there a recommended way to validate the presence of something like `admin[id]`?  We've written a method that makes the attempt, but it keeps puking (especially on new model creation) on `null` values, or if data is fetched from our DB with `null` values that are expected to be required (we are laying this app on top of existing data).

Here's our method for validating the presence of required fields:

```
validatePresence = function(requiredAttrs, submittedAttrs, errorsArr) {
  var regex = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g),
  attrStack = null,
  val = null,
  name = null;

  for( var l = requiredAttrs.length; --l >= 0; ) {
      attrStack = requiredAttrs[l].match(regex);
      val = submittedAttrs[attrStack.shift()];
      while(attrStack.length > 0) {
            console.log(requiredAttrs[l]);
          val = val[attrStack.shift()];
      }

      if( val === undefined ) { continue; }

      name = requiredAttrs[l];
      if( val === null || !val.length) {
          if( !errorsArr[name] ) {
              errorsArr[name] = [];
          }
          errorsArr[name].push("Oops, this can't be empty");
      }
  }
  return errorsArr; 
}
```

And here's the way we call it from within a BB model:

```
validate: function(attrs) {
  var requiredAttributes = ["name","admin[id]"],
  errors = {};
  errors = validatePresence(requiredAttributes, attrs, errors);
}
```

That method likes to choke on things like "admin[id]".  Any help is apprecaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not dead set on the bracket notation for your required attributes, you could draw some inspiration from this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799428/multiple-level-attribute-retrieval-using-array-notation-from-a-json-object/10799923#10799923) to simplify your validation.

Let's add a helper method to _ to extract the value of a given attribute:

```
_.findprop = function(obj, path) {
    var args = path.split('.'), i, l=args.length;

    for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i]))
            return;
        obj = obj[args[i]];
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Your `validate` method can then be rewritten as:

```
validate: function(attrs) {
    var requiredAttributes = ["name","admin.id"],
        errors = {}, i, l, v, attr;

    for (i=0, l=requiredAttributes.length; i<l; i++) {
        attr = requiredAttributes[i];
        v = _.findprop(attrs, attr);

        //checks if the value is truthy, to be adapted to your needs
        if (v) continue; 

        errors[attr] = errors[attr] || [];
        errors[attr].push("Oops, this can't be empty");
    }

    return errors;
}
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/FrtHb/2/

Comment: It is total insanity that there isn't a more modular way to extend Backbone.Model with this kind of functionality. Javascript really needs to set on an MOP framework that would provide this kind of stuff.